# Image Overlay plugin for FilePond Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filepond

I want a review button on image, but I don't find attribute.

I set the `imagePreviewMarkupShow = true` but it didn't work.

[Package here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/filepond-plugin-image-overlay)

**My Template**

```html
    <template>
        <div id="app">
             <file-pond
            name="test"
            ref="pond"
            max-files="4"
            label-idle="Drop files here..."
            :allow-multiple="true"
            accepted-file-types="image/jpeg, image/png"
            :files="myFiles"
            v-on:init="handleFilePondInit"
            allowImagePreview ="false"
            />

        </div>
    </template>
```

**My Script**

```js
    import  vueFilePond from 'vue-filepond';
    import 'filepond/dist/filepond.min.css';
    import 'filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.min.css';
    import FilePondPluginFileValidateType from 'filepond-plugin-file-validate-type';
    import FilePondPluginImagePreview from 'filepond-plugin-image-preview';

    import FilePondPluginImageOverlay from 'filepond-plugin-image-overlay';
    // Create component
    const FilePond = vueFilePond(FilePondPluginFileValidateType, FilePondPluginImagePreview,FilePondPluginImageOverlay);

    export default {
         name: 'app',
        data: function() {
            return { myFiles: [] };
        },
        methods: {

            handleFilePondInit: function() {
                console.log('FilePond has initialized');
    // this.$refs.pond.getFiles();
                // FilePond instance methods are available on `this.$refs.pond`
            }
        },
        components: {
            FilePond
        }
    };
```

How do I add that button?

Answer (score 2):

I was also struggling with this problem.
The solution is to import CSS.

```
import 'filepond-plugin-image-overlay/dist/filepond-plugin-image-overlay.min.css'
```

This is not mentioned in Github.

Comment: I know, but this css did not help me. And i did this way. i hope maybe one day, they are adds auxiliary class. :)